# Django Combining Multiple Filters for ManytoMany Choice

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to filter a ManyToMany field in a form on Django so that it only includes choices for the current user logged in users associated to the logged in user (parent and children)

forms.py

```
class LessonsForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = models.Lessons
    fields = ['type_of_lesson','attendees','max_capacity','teacher','date_of_lesson','time_of_lesson']

class LessonAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(LessonAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['attendees'].queryset = CustomUser.objects.filter(username=user)


class Meta:
    model = models.Lessons
    fields = ['attendees']
```

Models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
date_of_birth = models.DateField()
is_parent = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Parent")
children = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth', 'is_parent','email',]

class Lessons(models.Model):
type_of_lesson = models.CharField("Lesson Type", max_length=128)
attendees = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name="attendee_users")
max_capacity = models.IntegerField()
teacher = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="teaching_user",limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True})
date_of_lesson = models.DateField()
time_of_lesson = models.TimeField()
date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
```

the line below is where I am struggling, this brings back the current user but I am also trying to have the 'children' connect to the user also appear in the attendees choices.

```
self.fields['attendees'].queryset = CustomUser.objects.filter(username=user)
```

I have tried a few methods below is an example but I can't seem to figure how how to combine two filters

```
    self.fields['attendees'].queryset = CustomUser.objects.filter(username=user,user.children)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with [**`Q`** objects [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) and make use of a logical *or*:

```
from django.db.models import Q

self.fields['attendees'].queryset = CustomUser.objects.filter(
    Q(username=user) |
    Q(customuser__username=user)
)
```

The `customuser__` part is querying the `children` relation in *reverse*. So we are looking for `CustomUser`s where its parent has as `username` the given `user`.